# Docker - How to write a custom load balancer?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, load-balancing

For the sake of learning more about Docker, I want to try and write a custom load balancer. I’m thinking of creating a docker network using the default bridge driver and putting a load balancer application inside a proxy container for that network. I will run one or more services with multiple replicas, and the proxy will route traffic to each container using round robin.

I suppose that the proxy should be aware of all other instances that exist in the same network and the services they are offering in order to do load balancing. These are my ideas of doing it:

- For every container running in the network, send a request to the proxy to inform its availability status. I find this doable, but requires customizing all the containers (to send requests periodically).
- Make the proxy query the host for network status: I noticed that the command `docker network inspect` gives details about the network configurations as well as the containers running inside the network, so I think I can send this information to the proxy as well.

My question is: Which approach is preferred? Is the second approach even feasible? If yes, is there any guide or documentation I should look into for this? I have a little idea of operating systems and networking so any help to put those things together is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to look into the terms *Service Discovery* / *Service Registry* and how to use them together with your load-balancer.

From: [Service Discovery and Load Balancing](https://www.katacoda.com/getlevvel/courses/rhoar-spring-boot/microservices-2)

> ## Service Discovery
>
> When we're handling a microservice architecture, it's very possible that we have multiple services across multiple servers or even multiple data servers. While the end user might not care much about the location of any of these services, our application is highly concerned with the connection details for each service. This problem is addressed with `Service Discovery`.
>
> **1. What is Service Discovery?**
>
> As we mentioned, when services become spread out they become difficult to manage. It's tough to keep track of where each service is and what information details are needed to connect to each service. Service Discovery is exactly what it sounds like, the process of discovering all of our exposed services and how to connect with them.
>
> This process of keeping track of multiple services is solved with the use of a `Service Registry`. Each service registers with the Service Registry upon creation, and the Service Registry is responsible for handling and maintaining the information required to connect to each service.
>
> ...
>
> Since it's possible for microservices to go down from time to time, it's important to think of how that situation gets handled within the Service Registry. **Generally a Service Registry is paired with a load balancer layer** (mentioned in the previous section) that will seamlessly fail over upon discovering that the instance no longer exists. So if a service instance was to go down, the Service Registry would not be able to return the required information and the load balancer would kick in to handle it while also caching the service registry lookups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just now realized that using the word load-balancer in my original question is quite misleading